# Wix - Execute a CustomAction during Upgrade only

Tags: wix, wix3

I want to run a custom action only during Upgrade, so i added condition 
**'Installed AND UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE'**
but this is not working? What am i doing wrong?

Installed AND UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE

Answer (score 0):

You are always better off tying CustomActions to the install state of Components. However, UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE should be set. You might try appending `<>""`. A verbose log file would show more details.